# Spring-Boot error creating bean, startup fails ca. 50% of Time

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring-Boot application, where the startup sometimes fails, and sometimes, without changing anything in the Code, it works. Here's the Error:

```
Parameter 1 of constructor in ch.post.pf.quick2lunch.business.service.OrderService required a bean of type 'ch.post.pf.quick2lunch.repository.MenuOrderRepo' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'ch.post.pf.quick2lunch.repository.MenuOrderRepo' in your configuration.

06-Jul-2018 10:41:34.287 SCHWERWIEGEND [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/quick2lunch]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:441)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
```

The Annotaions should be okay.

Here's The MenuOrderRepo:

```
@Repository
public interface MenuOrderRepo extends JpaRepository<MenuOrder, Long> {
}
```

And here's the OrderService:

```
@Service
public class OrderService {

private final OrderRepo orderRepo;

private final MenuOrderRepo menuOrderRepo;

@Autowired
public OrderService(final OrderRepo orderRepo, final MenuOrderRepo menuOrderRepo) {
    this.orderRepo = orderRepo;
    this.menuOrderRepo = menuOrderRepo;
}
```

It's my first Project with Spring-Boot and I changed nothing in the configuration.

Comment: Remove `@Repository` and also add `@EnableJpaRepositories` with the matching scan.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your boot application aware about your repository classes.

so add `@EnableJpaRepositories("ch.post.pf.quick2lunch.repository")` in your spring boot main class.

Comment: Still doesn't work, the weird thing is, that the problem only appears with this Repo and all the others work, and even this Repo works sometimes. So the boot application should be aware about my repository classes.